# Upgraded Angular service not working in angular component :cannot get Undefined error

Tags: angular, ng-upgrade

I am working on upgrading an AngularJS app to angular.
But i have now gotten stuck.
I am tryting to get angular to handle the home route and doesn't work. The error appears to come from the upgraded service.

When i let angularJS handle the route it works fine using the same components.

App-routing.module

```
class HybridUrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
  // use only process the `home` url
  shouldProcessUrl(url:UrlTree) { 
    console.log(url.toString());
    return url.toString() === '/' || url.toString() ==='/home' ; 
  }
  extract(url: UrlTree) { return url; }
  merge(url: UrlTree, whole: UrlTree) { return url; }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponentNg2 }
];

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule ],
    providers:[
    { provide: UrlHandlingStrategy, useClass: HybridUrlHandlingStrategy }
    ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

ajs-upgraded-providers.ts

```
export function statsServiceFactory(i: any) {
  return i.get('StatsService');
}
export const StatsServiceProvider = {
  provide: StatsService,
  useFactory: statsServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
};

export function authServiceFactory(i:any){
  return i.get('AuthService');
}

export const AuthServiceProvider = {
  provide: AuthService,
  useFactory: authServiceFactory,
  deps: ['$injector']
```

stats.service

```
export class StatsService {
    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor(private $http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    };

    getEmplStats() {
        console.log('getEmplstats');
        return this.$http.get('./src/app/JSON/employeeStats.json')
            .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return res
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    };

    getCustStats() {
        console.log('getCustStats');
        return this.$http.get('./src/app/JSON/customerStats.json')
            .then(res => {
            console.log(" getCustStats "+res);
            return res
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
export default StatsService;
```

The error

```
core.es5.js?0445:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at statsServiceFactory (eval at 327 (http://localhost:8080/app.js:653:1), <anonymous>:6:13)
    at Ng2AppModuleInjector.get (ng:///Ng2AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:161:69)
    at Ng2AppModuleInjector.getInternal (ng:///Ng2AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:271:52)
    at Ng2AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:84:1), <anonymous>:3783:44)
    at resolveDep (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:84:1), <anonymous>:11245:45)
```

I just dont understand why letting AngularJS handle the route it seems to go fine but if i let Angular handle it, it falls apart. 
Any help would be apreciated

edit:Added the customer-stats.ng2.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'customer-stats2',
  templateUrl: './customer-stats.ng2.component.html'
})

export class CustomerStatsComponentNg2 implements OnInit{
    customerStats:any;

    constructor(private ss:StatsService){
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log('ngoninit cust stats ')
        this.ss.getCustStats().
            then(custStats => this.customerStats = custStats.data)
           .then(error => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

Comment: `import { Http } from '@angular/http'`

Comment: Sadly that didnt help. It confuses me because it works fine when angularJS handles the route.

Comment: You haven't added your service to your providers array? It would though throw a different error....

Comment: It is added there already , it is added via by importing the ajs-providers and adding the StatsServiceProvider. thx for trying.

Comment: The routing works if i remove the service from the component. I will add the component to see if it might help trouble shoot it but it seems its just the upgraded service that is causing the problem. The alternative would be to start initialy with the creating the angular versions of the service and downgrading them. But according to the tutorial this should be possible

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while trying to upgrade the angularjs service and use in angular. You can find the bug raised in the angular code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14239).

When we spoke to the angular team during the ng conference they mentioned that we might run into this problem if we are bootstrapping the ng2 application first and then ng1 application, they suggested to switch the bootstrapping process to do ng1 first and then ng2 will solve this problem. We haven't tried the switching bootstrap sequence yet, but hopefully that will solve your problem.

Comment: hmm intersting. I am following their guide so it is weird that its not working. Their guide also launches angular first to my knowledge. My current solution is to convert te services to angular services first and downgrading them for angularJS. This is not ideal but this seems like the only solution for me atm.

Comment: Actually we had a hacky solution, while bootstrapping angular application using platformBrowserDynamic we had access to these services through platformRef.injector, so at that point we attached them to a window object. In our case we had a lot of ng1 services so rewriting in ng2 is not a option for us.